# Beginner python programmer having some issues with pandas and sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

The Source of the original code is from https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-movie-recommender-using-python-277959b07dae.

The overall goal of this function is to create a content-based movie recommend system. I get that this code is creating a matrix. What I am trying to do is just print out the Title of the first movie that is recommended. My current print statement prints out the id, title, name, and type which isn't what I want and I think it has something to do with `.iloc`? I was thinking of just finding a way to solely get the title and add it to a list(in case I want to add more later) and then print the list, but unsure how to get just the title. As of now, the print shows:

```
15348    Toy Story 3
Name: title, dtype: object
```

Another issue I am running into is when a movie has a duplicate of the same name like 'The Avengers' I get an error. I tried `.drop_duplicate(keep='last')` but that still gave me an error and I'm unsure how to fix it. This is the traceback for when there are multiple movies with the same name:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH TO--> TestMovie/test.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(content_based_recommender('The Avengers'))
  File "PATH TO-->/TestMovie/test.py", line 31, in content_based_recommender
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

- 

```
    idx = indices[title]
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(sim_matrix[idx]))
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:2]
    movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
    print(movie_data['title'].iloc[movie_indices])
    return movie_data['title'].iloc[movie_indices]

content_based_recommender('Toy Story')
```

Comment: You say you get an error, could you post the traceback?

Comment: Added. Having that issue of a two movies of the same name and unsure how to just get the title out of the matrix when I print or return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) will select the specified rows of a dataframe or a series, so the return value will still be a dataframe/series. To get the actual values you can use [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) to get a array of values. In this case, since you know that there will only be a single value so you can use `.values[0]`, i.e.:

```py
movie_data['title'].iloc[movie_indices].values[0]
```

---

For the duplicate problem, you are actually not removing any duplicates. After creating the new `indices` series, the duplicates are in the index and are thus not removed. Instead, remove the duplicates before creating the series:

```py
indices = movie_data['title'].drop_duplicates().reset_index().set_index('title')['index']
```

Comment: That was so helpful! Removing the duplicates first did what I was trying. Thanks